# Get CURL PHP retrieves the data but cannot decode the json

Tags: php, json, curl, get

I have a GET cURL in PHP and want to retrieve and process an array. The cURL on site 1 (where the data should go) looks like this:

```
$curl = curl_init();

$id = 123;

$url = 'https://SITEURL/getMessage?id_link=' . $id;

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo "<pre>";
echo print_r(json_decode($result, true));
echo "</pre>";
exit();
```

The script on the site where the getMessage function is located (just as test this array):

```
$array = ['test', 'bla'];

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

When I echo result on site 1, I get the json out. However, when I do json decode then the entire json/array is gone and nothing comes out. When I do json error debugging I get a syntax error from json.

I checked for errors I get errorlog, no errors. The json error gave a syntax error, but unfortunately I can't do much with that.

Comment: Try echoing `$result` to see what you're actually getting, there may be something before/after the JSON.

Comment: @barmar i did before, thats the json i get out of it: ["test","bla"]

Comment: What does `echo json_last_error_msg();` show?

Comment: @barmar Thx for your reply, but i got syntax error as message. So i don't know whats wrong

Comment: Where did you put it? It should be before `echo "</pre>";`

Comment: @barmar yes, i did it like this:

`$result = curl_exec($ch);

        json_decode($result, true);

        echo json_last_error_msg();`

Comment: Oh, that's what `json_last_error_msg()` is returning. It's telling you that there's a syntax error in the JSON.

Comment: Are you displaying the result on a web page or a terminal? If you're calling the first script from a browser, look at the result of `var_dump($result);` in the Network tab, since there may be characters that the browser doesn't show.

Comment: @barmar omg i didnt knew that. It was sending wrong characters :O Thx bro!